# Pushpin size at WP7 map control

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, pushpin

while trying to implement logic that show current user location i encountered an issue.

```
<Maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding MyLocation}" Canvas.ZIndex="1000" PositionOrigin="Center"  >
            <Maps:Pushpin.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Width="{Binding MyAccuracyViewSize}" Height="{Binding MyAccuracyViewSize}"
                                 Fill="#60008000" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="18" Height="18" Fill="#A0FF4500" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Maps:Pushpin.Template>
        </Maps:Pushpin>
```

Bigger green circle shows accuracy area. Its size in pixels varies depending on zoom. If zoom level is big - it becomes rather big (> 480 pixels). At that point it gets cropped by screen resolution. AFAIK WP7 restriction is 2000x2000 px for control size.

Seems that this is a kind of a map control restriction.

Any ideas how to remove this restriction to show ellipse of size up to 2000x2000 px?

[image: Screenshot with this behavior]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to adjust the MyAccuracyViewSize based on the current zoom level value?

Comment: Of course. It shows area where user potentially can be. I know circle radius in meters. If i want to project it on map, i have to respect zoom level. 50 pixels with zoom==10 are for example 5km while with zoom==18 they are maybe 100meters.

Comment: Did you try scaling the circle instead of giving a higher pixel-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about MapPolygon?

```
void OnPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            SecondsCounter = 0; //reset counter
            double accuracy = e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy;
        if (accuracy < e.Position.Location.VerticalAccuracy)
        {
            accuracy = e.Position.Location.VerticalAccuracy;
        }

        if (PolyCircle == null)
        {
            PolyCircle = new MapPolygon();
            PolyCircle.Opacity = 0.7;
            //Set the polygon properties 

            PolyCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            PolyCircle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
            PolyCircle.StrokeThickness = 4;

            map1.Children.Add(PolyCircle);
        }

        PolyCircle.Locations = CreateCircle(e.Position.Location, accuracy);


        map1.Center = e.Position.Location;    

    }

    public static double ToRadian(double degrees)
    {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    public static double ToDegrees(double radians)
    {
        return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
    }

    public static LocationCollection CreateCircle(GeoCoordinate center, double radius)
    {
        var earthRadius = 6367000; // radius in meters
        var lat = ToRadian(center.Latitude); //radians
        var lng = ToRadian(center.Longitude); //radians
        var d = radius / earthRadius; // d = angular distance covered on earth's surface
        var locations = new LocationCollection();

        for (var x = 0; x <= 360; x++)
        {
            var brng = ToRadian(x);
            var latRadians = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Cos(d) + Math.Cos(lat) * Math.Sin(d) * Math.Cos(brng));
            var lngRadians = lng + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(brng) * Math.Sin(d) * Math.Cos(lat), Math.Cos(d) - Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Sin(latRadians));

            locations.Add(new GeoCoordinate(ToDegrees(latRadians), ToDegrees(lngRadians)));
        }

        return locations;
    }
```

More [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maps_Examples_for_Windows_phone), in My Map position example. Good luck!